# 4 or more columns how do you subtract the columns with data to get result

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you ask excel to subtract multiple columns of data with each row either having a value or not to get delta between the two columns that do have a value in them.  Ex.

(Row 1 / column A,B,C,D and E1 has results) A1=58, B1=0, C1=30,D1=0 and results in E1 would be 28
(Row 2 and colA-E same as above) A1=70, B1=0, C1=0, D1=40, and results in e1=30

Thank you - appreciate

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you need something like this: `=A1-SUM(B1:D1)`?

Comment: Sorry I stated the wrong type of values in the example.  The columns actually have different dates not values.  However like the example some do not have dates.  Column A will always have a date and the other columns may or maynot and the last column needs to be the result of column A minus whatever columne B,C,etc...has a date in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the number of days between the date in Col A and the date in Col B, C, or D (whichever is NOT empty), you can use the `DAYS360` formula. If you know columns B through D will only have one cell that is not empty, the formula in column E would look like this when using the U.S. date method:

```
=DAYS360(A1, SUM(B1:D1), FALSE)
```

If multiple cells in the row will have dates, and you want to take the first cell that has a value in columns B through D, something like this would work:

```
=DAYS360(A1, INDEX(B1:D1, MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(B1:D1),0)),FALSE).
```

That is an array formula so you'll need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the cell when completing the formula.